# Specify different Tab size for TSV files only

Tags: notepad++

I would like to specify a large tab size (say 16) for TSV files, but have normal tab size of 4 for other files/languages. I went View/UserDefinedDialog, made a new language, click SaveAs TSV. Specified file extension of tsv there, nothing else. Didn't see any tab options in the new lang dialog. Next I went to Setting/Preferences (tab: Languages/Tab Settings) expecting to see a new language of TSV in the list where I could set the larger tab size. But there is still no entry in that this for TSV. I can see TSV in the Language menu item, after the built in langs, and before the User Defined item.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not possible simply by configuration.

**Workaround 1:**

try associate TSV extension with built-in language you never use in N++ (e.g. Pascal) and which has only modest syntax coloring. Then set tab size for this language to 16.

**Workaround 2:**

Try playing with 2 parallel N++ instances, one for TSV files (which open as CSV files with tabssize=16), second for general use (CSV files with tabsize=4). You can achieve this by downloading version of N++ which comes in ZIP file and does NOT require an installer. Then configure the instances differently. Possible problem which you might need to solve here could be how the instances can avoid sharing their configuration.